# How do appDomain provide Isolation

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, appdomain

In my window forms application, I create a Appdomain say sandBox. In this sandbox i excute some code Say TestMethod from TestAppdomain Class. This class is in Test.dll which is not loaded in the current appdomain (Default appdomain).

Now while executing TestMethod some exception occurs, then I want the sandbox domain to be unloaded and since AppDOmain provide Isolotion my Default Appdomain shoud not be affected.

But As i read over the internet i guess this is not possible.But could some one give me some pointer on how to achive it.

Thanks in Advance

Vikram

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "then I want the sandbox domain to be uploaded" ?

Comment: Opps .. I wanted to say "Sandbox domain to be unloaded" and not uploaded.

Comment: Rundown of the isolation benefits of appdomains http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx

Comment: At end I implimented the code for isolation using idea from here http://thevalerios.net/matt/2008/06/run-anonymous-methods-in-another-appdomain/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is certainly possible, and in fact it is the entire purpose of AppDomains. A quick Google search turns up a good resource:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130512060833/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/elinden/archive/2008/09/12/application-processing-isolation-welcome-the-appdomain-object.aspx)

Above link is broken, this one provides an overview of `AppDomain` sharing.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810024340/http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/07/25/150301.aspx)

You may also want to look into the Managed Add-In Framework (MAF):

Comment: Yes AppDomains do Isolote. But if there is a exception in another domain then it does take down the application. I want to know how I can handle exception happening in a appdomain, and then unload it without affecting my base application.

Comment: Put a try/catch handler around the call from the default AppDomain into the secondary AppDomain.