# How to detect crashing tabed webbrowser and handle it?

Tags: c#, tabs, crash, browser

I have a desktop application (forms) with a tab control, I assign a tab and a new custom webrowser control.  I open up about 10 of these tabs. Each one visits about 100 - 500 different pages.

The trouble is that if 1 webbrowser control has a problem it shuts down the entire program.

I want to be able to close the offending webbrowser control and open a new one in it's place.

Is there any event that I need to subscribe to catch a crashing or unresponsive webbrowser control ?

I am using C# on windows 7 (Forms), .NET framework v4

===============================================================

## **UPDATE: 1 - The Tabbed WebBrowser Example**

Here is the code I have and How I use the webbrowser control in the most basic way.

1. Create a new forms project and name it SimpleWeb
2. Add  a new class and name it myWeb.cs, here is the code to use.

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Text;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
> using System.Security.Policy;
>
> namespace SimpleWeb
> {
>     //inhert all of webbrowser
>     class myWeb : WebBrowser
>     {
>
>         public myWeb()
>         {
>             //no javascript errors
>             this.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
>
>             //Something we want set?
>             AssignEvents();
>         }
>
>         //keep near the top
>         private void AssignEvents()
>         {
>
>             //assign WebBrowser events to our custom methods
>             Navigated += myWeb_Navigated;
>             DocumentCompleted += myWeb_DocumentCompleted;
>             Navigating += myWeb_Navigating;
>             NewWindow += myWeb_NewWindow;
>
>         }
>
>
>         #region Events
>         //List of events:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_events%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
>
>         //Fired when a new windows opens
>         private void myWeb_NewWindow(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
>         {
>             //cancel all popup windows
>             e.Cancel = true;
>             //beep to let you know canceled new window
>             Console.Beep(9000, 200);
>         }
>
>
>         //Fired before page is navigated (not sure if its before or during?)
>         private void myWeb_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs args)
>         {
>
>         }
>
>         //Fired after page is navigated (but not loaded)
>         private void myWeb_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs args)
>         {
>
>         }
>
>
>         //Fired after page is loaded (Catch 22 - Iframes could be considered a page, can fire more than once. Ads are good examples)
>         private void myWeb_DocumentCompleted(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs args)
>         {
>
>         }
>
>
>         #endregion
>
>
>
>         //Answer supplied by mo. (modified)?
>         public void OpenUrl(string url)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 //this.OpenUrl(url);
>                 this.Navigate(url);
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 MessageBox.Show("Your App Crashed! Because = " + ex.ToString());
>                 //MyApplication.HandleException(ex);
>             }
>         }
>
>
>
>         //Keep near the bottom
>         private void RemoveEvents()
>         {
>             //Remove Events
>             Navigated -= myWeb_Navigated;
>             DocumentCompleted -= myWeb_DocumentCompleted;
>             Navigating -= myWeb_Navigating;
>             NewWindow -= myWeb_NewWindow;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

1. On Form1 drag a standard tabControl and set the dock to fill, you can go into the tab collection and delete the pre-populated tabs if you like.
2. Right Click on Form1 and Select "View Code" and replace it with this code.

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.ComponentModel;
> using System.Data;
> using System.Drawing;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Text;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
> using mshtml;
>
> namespace SimpleWeb
> {
>     public partial class Form1 : Form
>     {
>         public Form1()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>
>
>             //Load Up 10 Tabs
>             for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
>             {
>                 newTab("Test_" + i, "http://wwww.yahoo.com");
>
>             }
>         }
>
>
>         private void newTab(string Title, String Url)
>         {
>
>             //Create a new Tab
>             TabPage newTab = new TabPage();
>             newTab.Name = Title;
>             newTab.Text = Title;
>
>             //create webbrowser Instance
>             myWeb newWeb = new myWeb();
>
>             //Add webbrowser to new tab
>             newTab.Controls.Add(newWeb);
>             newWeb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
>
>             //Add New Tab to Tab Pages
>             tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTab);
>
>             newWeb.OpenUrl(Url);
>
>
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Save and Run the project.

Using the answer below by mo. , you can surf the first url with no problem, but what about all the urls the user clicks on?  How do we check those?

I prefer not to add events to every single html element on a page, there has to be a way to run the new urls thru the function OpenUrl before it navigates without having an endless loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Modern browsers deal with this by running each tab in a separate process. That's the *right* solution.

Comment: This is why chrome uses a separate process for each tab

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'd say that right solution in .net would be using different `AppDomain`s, not processes.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev - Can you provide an example of how this is done? Google is not being helpfull.  Or was this a joke that 1 webbrowser should be used per application?

Comment: @DavidEaton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178872/how-do-appdomain-provide-isolation

Comment: @SergRogovtsev Not really. AppDomains don't isolate from errors in native code (memory corruption, etc.); plugins, ActiveX controls, even the underlying component of the WebBrowser control itself, all contain native code. Processes is the only safe way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) or [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception) event.

But handling exceptions this way may end up in having an **invalid state** in your application.

Could you describe, when these exceptions occur.
Are they a result of executing a method?

Then it is much better to handle the error in the calling method.

```
void OpenUrl(Url url)
{
   try
   {
       var webBrowser = GetWebBrowser(tabControl.SelectedTab);
       webBrowser.OpenUrl(url);
   }
   catch(SpecificException ex)
   {
       MyApplication.HandleException(ex);
   }
}
```

in respect to your comment, try this:

```
try
{
   myCustomWebbrowser.Navigate("yahoo.com");
}
catch(Exception ex) //catch specific exceptions here (catch all is a bad practice)
{
   MessageBox.Alert(ex.Message); //just for testing.
}
```

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-2-0-WebBrowser-Control) should help you out:

```
private void AssignEvents()
{
  Navigated += myWeb_Navigated;
  DocumentCompleted += myWeb_DocumentCompleted;
  Navigating += myWeb_Navigating;
  NewWindow += myWeb_NewWindow;
  DownloadComplete += myWen_DownloadComplete;
}

void myWen_DownloadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Check wheter the document is available (it should be)
  if (Document != null)
    // Subscribe to the Error event
    Document.Window.Error += myWeb_Window_Error;
}

void myWeb_Window_Error(object sender, HtmlElementErrorEventArgs e)
{
  // We got a script error, record it
  ScriptErrorManager.Instance.RegisterScriptError(e.Url, 
                           e.Description, e.LineNumber);
  // Let the browser know we handled this error.
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to work in your solution, I only call myCustomWebbrowser.Navigate("http://www.yahoo.com"); once is there a way to tell the webbrowser to use OpenUrl instead?  I am putting OpenURL inside the webbrowser control?  Since it calls itself will this make it catch the error, not sure if this was done on purpose or not?  Instead of webBrowser.OpenUrl I am using this.OpenUrl(url)

Comment: then simply wrap this method-call. (sample in my answer)

Comment: This would work for the very first url but what about the other pages the webbrowser craws, is there a way to catch urls from navigate assuming that the webbrowser calls navigate when a person manually clicks a link in the webbrowser?  Can navigate be overridden some how?

Comment: Hi David, which "browser"-control do you use? sometimes such controls offer an event to handle special cases.

Comment: I am using the standard webbrowser  Systems.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser but I am wraping it in my own class so that I can control various elements.

Comment: I provided more source code on how I am using the webbrowser control  Hopefully it would provide some more ideas on how to do this.

Comment: May be this helps, what type of exception do you get?

Comment: Some times it's an APPCrash (because of flash or something loaded in browser)  and sometimes a BEX Error (The dreaded can't read or write to memory)  I have tried running these AppDomain.UnhandledException or Application.ThreadException in Program.cs and nothing gets thrown.  I went as far as try, catch the main just to see what's exception is getting triggered but nothing.  It's kinda late (Today was labor day), I will try your code above and see what it does. You been most Helpful so far.

Comment: After testing code the example provided does not work with .net 4  I guess I can either deal with it, or look for another solution that will allow to detect a crash, but I am having a hard time finding another solution that allow access to DOM the way Web browser did.